# How to solve memory leak cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I solve this kind memory leak problem? Please help.

```
@interface ParseOperation () <NSXMLParserDelegate>
// Redeclare appRecordList so we can modify it.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *appRecordList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *dataToParse;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *workingArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AppRecord *workingEntry;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *workingPropertyString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *elementsToParse;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL storingCharacterData;
@end
```

[image]

Comment: ARC is off I found  a tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHWGUwYMGBw to detect memory leak,according to it I kept arc off

Comment: can you show error message? in what class does it happens (name of class)? show pls header of class (or extension) - where did you define workingEntry and storinCharactedData

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use ARC?

Comment: When I use Xcode's analyzer I get numbered explanations but they are not present in the image you posted. What do they say?

Comment: @Zaph to remember the good old days or to learn manual reference counting, which isn't a bad idea, since it will help you understand how ARC works.

Comment: If you're not using ARC, why are you using Strong? It should be retain. Check out https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html Half your code gives the impression you are using ARC and the other half gives the impression you're not.

Answer (score 2):

You can either autorelease:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:kEntryStr]) {
    self.workingEntry = [[[AppRecord] new] autorelease];
}
```

or simply release:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:kEntryStr]) {
    self.workingEntry = [[AppRecord] new];
    [self.workingEntry release];
}
```

By the way, new is same as alloc + init.

Comment: I always use new too - it's a shame you so rarely see it used. +1

Comment: @David I agree. The reason we see it so rarely is because for many years Apple advised us not to. About a year ago Apple started using `new` in some of their docs so the policy seems to have changed.

Comment: Please show me anything in writing that proves apple advised against its use! New has been around since Next. When Apple wants you to stop using some method they deprecate it, and this method has nevertheless been deprecated. I've been using it for almost 10 years!

Comment: Now I have enabled ARC,still getting memory leak   dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{
        NSData *request=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif"]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            weather_icon.image=[UIImage imageWithData:request];//memory leak
        });
    });

Comment: @user2799156, posting code in a comment is not really advisable. Also I think that is a different question, so you should ask a new question for that one if you cannot figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Since ARC is disabled, you need to autorelease your AppRecord instance when you create it.

```
self.workingEntry = [[[AppRecord alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: It doesn't matter that `workingEntry` is a strong property. It would be the same if it was weak. Also, he needs to release it, but not necessarily with an autorelease.

Comment: If I remember correctly if they aren't using ARC then putting strong or weak will not make a difference. It should be retain not strong.

Comment: `retain` and `strong` are equivalents.

Comment: I will stand corrected I have just been reading through the docs quickly strong is the equivalent of retain but the docs do say practice dictates that when not using ARC you should use retain and when you are you should use strong. But we're not here to discuss best practice now are we.

Comment: When you say you have enabled ARC, what exactly did you do? It's not like a check box you can switch on and off.

Comment: Actually it's pretty much like a checkbox. ARC can be enabled/disabled  for each different obj-C source file in your project settings, so you can mix it up if needed. In ARC projects you can use the `-fobjc-no-arc` flag for non-ARC sources. For non-ARC projects you can use the `-fobj-arc` to mark sources as ARC enabled.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not a retain circle, it's just memory leak.

### Leak

In your situation workingEntry is strong property. That mean, that setter of workingEntry is something like:

```
- (void)setWorkingEntry:(AppRecord *)workingEntry {
    if (workingEntry != _workingEntry){
        [_workingEntry release];
        _workingEntry = [workingEntry retain];
    }
}
```

As you can see after setWorkingEntry: property will have retainCounter at least 1, that will be decreased in dealloc by [_workingEntry release]; and in normal case retain counter should be 0 to free that instance, but in you case you set [[AppRecord alloc] init] (that also have +1 retain counter). So in this case in dealloc you will have _workingEntry with retain counter = 2, after you release it, retain counter will became = 1 and will never be freed. So release in after setting to make retain counter normalized:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:kEntryStr]) {
    self.workingEntry = [[AppRecord] new]; // or [[AppRecord alloc] init]
    [self.workingEntry release];
}
```

### Retain circle

Retain circle occurs when two (or more) objects have strong references to each other, and that links released, for example, in deallocs of that classes. In such situation they will never be released, because there will be at least one strong link to them at any moment (from other object, that also can't be freed).